# Merging tags or creating synonyms

Tags: discussion

Should we start merging similar tags (like events and civievent), or keep all of the similar versions and set them up as synonyms with the "main" tag?

Answer (score 4):

I've done some testing and reading, and I think merge is preferred for a couple of use cases. It cleans up the multiple tags *and* creates a synonym for them at the same time to prevent the bad tag from coming back (singular vs plural, misspelling, etc). So if there are tags that we think may need to be broken back up in the future, we would create a synonym but not merge them.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, but maybe the advantage of synonyms is that if we delete e.g. the "event" tag, someone new will just come along and create it again.

Answer (score 0):

I too favour creating synonyms of tags as a way of reducing tedious unnecessary work. Thanks for raising the topic Nicholai.