# How should we name tags - following CiviCRM components or general concepts?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms

We are getting some tags that should probably become synomyms, like `contributions` and `civicontribute` or `civimember` and `memberships`. Another meta question already discusses whether we should merge these or create synonyms: [Merging tags or creating synonyms](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/merging-tags-or-creating-synonyms)

What do you think should the "primary" tag be named? Should we prefer things like `civicontribute` which is refering to the CiviCRM structure directly or rather use the more general terms like `contributions`?